# Enable the status bar in the Windows Phone javascript templates for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

Does anyone know how to enable the status bar (picture) in a javascript Windows Phone 8.1 application? I am using the javascript Pivot Template in Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2.

[image]

Comment: it took me a while to find this question because first I was searching for "title bar" "phone bar" "action bar" "application bar" "app bar" .. but it turns out it is "status bar" or rather "statusbar" :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to add some JavaScript to the ready function of a page for example.

First get the statusbar for the current view. Than decide what to do with it:

```
var s = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.getForCurrentView();
s.showAsync(); // shows the statusbar
```

More about the statusbar can be found at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

@Sorskoot 's answer helped me a lot, but still I just spend an hour finding **HOW TO CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE STATUS BAR**. So I will share (as enabling status bar and setting it's color usually go together):

The code below shows the statusbar (or as the name suggests 
submits request to the message queue to do that)

```
var s = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.getForCurrentView();
s.showAsync();
```

If you try setting colors like this

```
// THIS IS WRONG
s.backgroundColor = 'red';
s.backgroundColor = '#A65959';
```

this will NOT work, throwing you error: 
`0x800a13ec - JavaScript runtime error: Could not convert object to struct:  object missing expected property 'a'`

This happens because s.backgroundColor is 
 not HTML object, but WinRT runtime object, thus we need to use 'Color' structure
of the WinRT, which has little to do with the HTML/JS color concepts.

But first lets first fix transparency (opacity). 
By default bg layer of the bar is fully transparent. Set it's opacity 
to 1.0 to make it fully opaque.

**TL;DR;**

```
// THIS IS RIGHT
s.backgroundOpacity = 0.99; 
s.backgroundColor = Windows.UI.ColorHelper.fromArgb(255, 0xA6, 0x59, 0x59);
s.foregroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.lightGray;
```

Above we use helper class to build a WinRT Color structure. Mind that opacity 
is in range 0-255 in helpers arguments. However in s.backgroundOpacity it is 
float in range [0..1] `>:o`

There's a bunch of predefined color constants in `Windows.UI.Colors`, but **mind 
camelCasing** (eg. `lightGray`), which is different from HTML/JS color naming convention)